# Simple xml returns no values when trying to access nodes

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Hi guys very new to the php world.

I am listening for a PHP post that contains xml, when the xml is retrieved i need to access individual nodes. I am able to echo the full xml file but not individual attributes.

Currently I am just sending the data using a chrome extension Postman. There is no front end code. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
<job_ref>abc123</job_ref>
<job_title>Test Engineer</job_title>
</job>
```

And here is my PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');  
echo $xml;
$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml);
echo $xml->job_ref . "<br>";
echo $xml->job_title . "<br>";
}else{
    die();
}
```

Any hep wopuld be amazing am I am very stuck.

Many thanks

Comment: You have to explicitly convert node to `string` if you want to output its content: `(string)$xml->job_ref`

Comment: hi hindmost -> could you explain your answer further

Comment: Add output of your script

Comment: Of which script, I am sending the data over using postman -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Comment: Add output in your question

Comment: It just returns the xml from the echo $xml and then to <br><br> but no job_ref or job_title

Comment: Got it I was using simplexml_load_file and not simplexml_load_string

Answer (score 0):

`simplexml_load_file` expect PATH to the XML file, not its content. You have to use `simplexml_load_string` instead:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```